# Left align with maximum margin

Tags: html, css

I have 3 elements `a`,`b`,`c` in one div. The size of `a` and `c` are fixed, whereas `b` can change its size. How can I align c, such that b can change its size but doesn't affect the positioning of c?

[image]

I made a mockup to make it clearer. I'm locking for a `maximum-margin`, or something like that.

I also added a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5LKL/). IF you change the width of `.b`, `.c` should remain on the same place. This is currently not the case.

Comment: set min-width for "b".. It will be better if you share your code in fiddle?

Comment: I'll make an example in fiddle

Comment: Is this what you want? [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j5LKL/2/) (_resize to check_)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set width for outer container and you can float .a,.c  like this: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j5LKL/1/)**

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="a"></div>
    <div class="b"></div>
    <div class="c"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
    width:600px;
}
.a {
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.b {
    width: 10px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.c {
    float:right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.a,.b,.c{
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
}
```

Updated **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/j5LKL/8/)** - with specified .b width and margin

Comment: Floating to the right works, but is there a possibility to align c on a with some margin?

Comment: some margin means.. I gave margin-left for all div's (.a,.b,.c). do you want space between .b and .c as shown in d pic even if there is / no content.

Comment: Yes, let'a say the `fixed distance` should be 200px. Then b can grow up to 200px minus margin between a and b

Comment: i updated my answer.. can you check and tell me is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RR2c4/12/)

```
.a,.c
{
 width: 100px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: red;
 display:inline-block;
}
.b
{
 height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align:top;

}
```

Change width and check. I assuemd total width doesnt exceed 100%.

Comment: What about this answer @Razer

Comment: I don't want to be b fixed. It should resize depending on the content

Comment: Remove width and add content . it ll work as u expected

Answer (score 0):

You can `float` `.a`,`.c` and centered `.b`

```
#wrapper{text-align:center;}
#wrapper:after{
    display:block;
    content:'';
    clear:both;
}
.a,
.c{
    float:left;
    width:150px;
    text-align:left;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}
.c{float:right;}
.b{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/86y8y/)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="d">
<span class="a">aa</span>
<span class="b">bb</span>
<span class="c">cc</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.a,.c
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    display:inline-block;
}
.b
{
    width:100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    display:inline-block;
}
.d{
white-space:nowrap;
width:350px;
display:inline-block;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RR2c4/4/)